# Как переместить элемент массива на другой индекс в Java?

Tags: java

К примеру есть массив:

```
List<RowItem> data = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
```

С 5 элементами

```
data.add(new RowItem("Элемент: 0"));
data.add(new RowItem("Элемент: 1"));
data.add(new RowItem("Элемент: 2"));
data.add(new RowItem("Элемент: 3"));
data.add(new RowItem("Элемент: 4"));
```

Нужно переместить - "Элемент: 3" на вторую позицию, чтобы получилось:

```
"Элемент: 0"
"Элемент: 3"
"Элемент: 1"
"Элемент: 2"
"Элемент: 4"
```

Пробовал удалить и добавить по индексу,

```
RowItem item = data.get(3); // Получаю объект "Элемент: 3" 
data.remove(3);
data.add(1, item);
```

но после удаления объект пропадал и ссылка стала - null.

Также делал с помощью метода set, но он меняет позиции местами а мне нужно чтобы "Элемент: 2" добавился на вторую позицию index 1, а "Элемент: 1" переместился на index 2.

```
RowItem row = data.get(1);
data.set(1, data.get(3));
data.set(3, row);
```

абсолютно тоже что и:

```
Collections.swap(data, 1, 3);
```

Как правильно перемещать объекты в массиве?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RowItem item = data.remove(3);
data.add(1, item);
```

и, кстати, это не массив!